# Creating a Flot line chart with dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to create a line chart using Flot that shows the month and year on the x axis corresponding to a number on the y axis.

Here is my code:

```
var data= [];
var y = 1;
var x;  

var record=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");
for(i=0;i<record.length;i++)
{
    x = record[i].getElementsByTagName("date_of_consent")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    x = x * 1000
    y = y + i;
    newArray = [x, y];
    data.push(newArray);
}

    var dataset = [{label: "Enrollment Over Time",data: data}];

    var options = {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: {
                radius: 3,
                show: false
            }
        }

    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%y/%m"
    }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), dataset, options);
    });
```

For reference the date_of_consent field has values similar to this: 1376092800000. The problem seems to be converting this number to a date. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: When you checked your javascript console for errors what did it say?  Also, why is the `$.plot` call wrapped in a `.ready` but not your parsing code?

Comment: Are you referring to the for loop? I am calling an XML file and referencing that file to create the data for the chart. I am under the impression that I can create the data array before calling the `$.plot` function. I am new to Flot, so correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The flot call is in a `$(document).ready`, this is good practice as flot relies on the DOM being complete before drawing.  Your XML parsing is not, though.  It shouldn't matter unless your parsing relies on the DOM being rendered.  Did you check your javascript console for errors?

Comment: @Mark It is returning an unexpected identifier on the `xaxis`. I have the jquery.js, jquery.flot.min.js, jquery.flot.js, jquery.flot.time.js, and the jquery.flot.axislabels.js files, but am I forgetting one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a javascript syntax error:

```
var options = {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        points: {
            radius: 3,
            show: false
        }
    }, <-- YOU ARE MISSING THIS COMMA!!
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        timeformat: "%y/%m"
    }
};
```

As you code, frequently inspect the javascript console for errors.